# Get notifications when AWS Lambda timesout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to get notifications when my AWS Lambda function times out?

I am unable to find any documentation. The only way as of now is to search through the Cloudwatch logs for timeout notifications of all the Lambda functions I have. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created an alarm in CloudWatch for a Lambda metric of type "Duration" and selected the Statistic of "Maximum" to alert me when the execution duration is greater/equal 30000 (= 30 seconds) for a Lambda function configured with a timeout of 30 seconds.

If the duration of a single execution ("maximum" of the period) exceeds the timeout time, you will be notified. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html), a timeout should be in the Errors metric. I observed weird behaviour with the count (e.g. having an error count of 0.5). Hence I made a CloudWatch alarm for the errors count > 0 (not >= 1).

You could also do something with the `REPORT` message or with

```
Task timed out after 25.00 seconds
```

which can be found in the Cloudwatch logs.

Answer (score 4):

You can have CloudWatch trigger an alarm when a certain message shows up in the logs. I can't seem to find any official documentation on this, but you create a "Metric Filter" in CloudWatch Logs, and then you can create an alarm from from that. [This blog post](https://blog.opsgenie.com/2014/08/how-to-use-cloudwatch-to-generate-alerts-from-logs) seems to describe the process well.

Comment: The link in that blog is now [here](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/opsgenie/how-to-use-cloudwatch-to-generate-alerts-from-logs). Also, for Slack integration, using a CloudWatch alarm, see this [article](https://medium.com/pixelpoint/how-to-send-aws-cloudwatch-alarms-to-slack-502bcf106047). However, for sending to Slack, could just directly go to [Slack's REST API](https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending). Combination of these seems ideal for me for now...

Answer (score 0):

I could receive SNS notification (email) by creating a [metric filter and an alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html#cloudwatch-alarms-metric-filter-alarm) whenever a lambda function timed out or provisioned throughput exceeded on a Dynamo table -

```
:
error: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.
:
:
2022-06-08T06:09:07.427+05:30   REPORT RequestId: c6acc2ca-ee60-495a-a554-bb76a9943430 Duration: 10019.19 ms Billed Duration: 10000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 236 MB
2022-06-08T06:09:07.427+05:30   2022-06-08T00:39:07.426Z c6acc2ca-ee60-495a-a554-bb76a9943430 Task timed out after 10.02 seconds 
:
```

Refer to doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html
for the detailed steps on setting up "metric filter and an alarm"

Summary of steps,

a) identify the pattern you are looking for in the cloudwatch log

b) Create a metric filter on the log group related to the lambda function

- provide a filter pattern to match any one of the possible text in the log:

  ?"timed out" ?error ?"ProvisionedThroughputExceededException"

c) create an alarm for the filter

- create sns topic
- provide email to receive notification on

This helped in tuning the capacity (RCU, WCU) set on the Dynamo table and also the timeout settings on lambda function. Hope this helps someone..